# No sound ARM Samsung Chromebook Ubuntu 12.04 using Crouton

Tags: 12.04, sound, xfce, chromebook

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 with xfce on my ARM Samsung Chromebook 3 using Crouton. The sound is not working however.  When I try to configure the sound using GStreamer I get

> GStreamer was unable to detect any sound devices.  Some sound system specific GStreamer packages may be missing.  It may also be a permissions problem.

The fixes I've found through so far haven't helped.

Similar to this user here, I can't find how to implement this fix.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/413293/samsung-arm-chomebook-no-sound-in-dual-os-with-crouton

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this same problem by doing a chrome os recovery and re-downloading crouton. *BUT* install crouton using the following

```
sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -t xfce -r raring -e
```

instead of the command

```
sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -t xfce -r raring
```

It should ask you for a pass-phrase and a password. Just use your password for all of that. When you start crouton using `sudo startxfce4` enter in your password and then it will not happen again. Make sure you backup all of your data you want to keep before doing this process though.