# No Sound in ARM HP Chromebook Ubuntu 14.04 with Crouton

Tags: sound, 14.04, xfce, alsa

UPDATE: I finally got my sound to work! All I had to do was update crouton. The following link explains how to do it: http://pastebin.com/uMJyYA4n

I replaced "raring" with "trusty" because I'm running 14.04.

In addition to this, I also reinstalled Pulseaudio and everything worked fine afterwards.

As the title suggests, I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 with XFCE on my chromebook. Sound worked initially, but after my first restart, I stopped getting any sound altogether. I have tried virtually all the workarounds found online, including installing and reinstalling pulseaudio and alsamixer.

When I try to access alsamixer via terminal, I receive the following error: "CRAS client wouldn't connect".

In addition, I'm unable to launch the audio mixer as it gives me the following error: "GStreamer was unable to detect any sound devices. Some sound system specific GStreamer packages may be missing. It may also be a permissions problem."

[No sound ARM Samsung Chromebook Ubuntu 12.04 using Crouton](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449073/no-sound-arm-samsung-chromebook-ubuntu-12-04-using-crouton?newreg=b055022c6e294c728ed2f968b26738df)

This user reports an identical problem and I've seen numerous other posts reporting the same issue.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Thank you.

Comment: Same happened to me. Sound worked initially, updated ChromeOS yesterday and there is no sound in the chroot. Running 13.10. I updated crouton and it didn't do anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No sound ARM Samsung Chromebook Ubuntu 12.04 using Crouton](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449073/no-sound-arm-samsung-chromebook-ubuntu-12-04-using-crouton)

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading crouton didn't do the trick for me, until I realized you said you installed pulseaudio, so don't forget that step if you are having trouble.  A simple "sudo apt-get install pulseaudio" in trusty, and with the newest crouton, and at least the my C720, you should have sound.  (I did also install the restricted drivers,but not sure if that did anythin, but worth mentioning).

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a result of the latest Chromebook update.. because it's not just 14.04. I was on 13.10 when it happened :s.
(I'm also on the Acer C720P)

It seems to have impacted CRAS.. which I know absolutely nothing about.

Hopefully Google hasn't decided to work against Chromebook/Linux users. I'm actually getting ready to completely reinstall Ubuntu with hopes of fixing, I'll update when I'm finished, although I'm not hopeful.

For anyone else, I'd advise avoid updating ChromeOS if possible just to be safe, for the time being.