# Ubuntu 14.04, Intel Chromebook, no sound

Tags: sound, chromebook

I am a total newbie to Ubuntu, and I'm not sure what to do here. I have a Toshiba Chromebook. I had a friend install the latest version of Ubuntu on it for me. For a while, the audio in Ubuntu was working fine, but now I can't hear any audio whatsoever.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps other Linux users on their Chromebooks with the BayTrail hardware.

I bought a new FHD Toshiba Chromebook, installed Mint 17.3 Xfce4 on it straight away (modified the BIOS & conductive sticker).

Everything rocked except for the sound.... my symptom was that I only had the HDMI outputs, no speakers, no analog.

To fix this I did the following:

1. Update the kernel version from 3. something to 4.2.0-23 by using the update manager. (start the gui version of the update manager, click **View > Linux Kernels**, click at least the 4.2.0-23 version)
2. Update / install the `linux-firmware` package:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
   ```
3. Download this Intel blob (click the link to download)

   https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware/+/refs/heads/master/intel/fw_sst_0f28.bin-48kHz_i2s_master

   Store it here:

   ```
   /lib/firmware/intel
   ```
4. Download the modified sound config file (`asound.state`) from https://gist.github.com/n1trux/3751a87f374a8af5f611
   Open a terminal window and type

   ```
   sudo alsa force-unload
   ```

   This temporarily kills the audio services.

   Replace the system’s sound config file with the downloaded version:

   ```
   sudo cp ~/Downloads/asound.state /var/lib/alsa
   ```
5. Reboot, open `pavucontrol` and unmute your analog speakers, also perhaps check `alsamixer`: speaker should be enabled or allowed to be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem recently after updating my Toshiba chromebook which runs Ubuntu 14.10 using crouton. The sound stopped working (although it did detect an output device "cras"). An update to crouton (instructions [here](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton)) solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check sounds in the system settings to ensure that your computer is not trying to play through an HDMI device.  The computer I am using has only a single audio capable device, but my other computer has both, and the HDMI output is silent (unless plugged into something).

[image]

Comment: That white box is completely empty for me... What does that mean?

Comment: That would indicate that ubuntu does not see any sound devices in your computer.  You might try adding support for the non-free firmware (the firmware with no sourcecode available)  `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`

Comment: I tried that, still no sound devices. :(

Comment: You could try the suggestions in this link  http://askubuntu.com/questions/470876/no-sound-in-arm-hp-chromebook-ubuntu-14-04-with-crouton

Comment: I followed the link that person posted. When I entered the command into the terminal, it said : /usr/local/chroots/raring does not exist; cannot update. did i download it wrong?

Comment: Try to launch alsamixer , see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/Alsamixer  , do you have some faders ? Also try to really stop your computer,  remove battery, wait a few seconds  .