# Sound not working on HP Chromebook 11 G4 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, chromebook, chromeos

I installed Seabios and then used a USB to install Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with no problems; I completely removed Chrome OS.

I just realized while playing a game that the sound is not working. Do I need to install a driver or just make some adjustments in `alsamixer` or similar?

Comment: I found the answer it is found here!!! http://askubuntu.com/a/730205/491308

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use another distribution meant specifically for Chromebooks. I use GalliumOS.

For any Chromebook you can look the compatibility with yours.
https://wiki.galliumos.org/Hardware_Compatibility

For myself I have the exact same laptop and I install the bay trail on the fallowing link. 
https://galliumos.org/download

I wish I knew it sooner.

Marc